# Getting handle of hidden form

Tags: c#, winforms

I need to open my form completely hidden, but I need a form handle to be able to send messages to it.

Currently using the following code to prevent form to show up:

```
protected override void SetVisibleCore(bool value)
{
    if (!IsHandleCreated && value)
    {
        base.CreateHandle();
        value = false;
    }
    base.SetVisibleCore(value);
}
```

It's working fine. But the problem is that when I request a handle to that form, it shows up and is no longer hidden:

```
string handle = this.Handle.ToString();
```

Of course I can then set `this.Hide()`, but for a short moment, the form is showing.

Is there any way to start and keep form hidden, while still be able to get handle to it?

Comment: Maybe you could hack a workaround using opacity?

Comment: Oh, of course. That worked fine, thanks :) Another problem that I just realized, is that when I hide & show a form, the form handle changes...

Comment: start the form minimized.

Comment: Using the Handle property cannot make the window visible.  Use the debugger, set a breakpoint on SetVisibleCore().  The second time it hits is the problem scenario.  The stack trace should reveal the code that makes it visible.

Comment: Ok, when I use the Handle property, does it mean that the form creates the handle at the same time? If so, that's the reason 'value = false' code never gets executed (because handle is already created) and 'SetVisibleCore' is never set to 'false'.